# Install4j - macOS single bundle

Tags: install4j

I have native macOS application and I need to wrap it to Install4j.
I'm able to make media: macOS folder only. I'm trying to change media type to macOS single bundle, but launcher is required for this bundle. I need to use 'macOS single bundle' because 'macOS folder' media automatically creates folder for application and customer doesn't want it.

I found that macOS single bundle accept only 'Generated launcher' not 'External launcher'. But 'Generated launcher' is for java application only, isn't it?
So is there any way how to make 'macOS single bundle' media for native macOS application?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of install4j 7.0, using a native executable for the single bundle media file on macOS is not supported.